# C# picturebox how do I get the image X and Y coordinates

Tags: c#, image, coordinates, picturebox

I have a picturebox inside a panel and an image loaded.

```
pictureBox1.AutoSize = true;
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

The image does not fill the picturebox.
How do I get the XY coordinates within the image, I want to add text to the image.
I am able to add the text to the image just not where I want the text.

```
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
          {
                g.DrawString( txt, fnt, myBrush, pnt.X, pnt.Y + panel1.Top );               
            }
```

several things
last

```
 `text`lbPnt = GetScaledImageLocation(lbPnt);`
```

Comment: There is no such thing a s a "C# PictureBox". Very probably you mean the Windows Forms PictureBox, in this case you should add a tag "winforms" to your question.

Comment: picturebox using C#